# MockitoException: Failed to mock class com.example.example.test.MainActivity

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, android-testing

I tried to install **Mockito** and got that **error message**. I'll be back to add my own answer when I get it.

It happens for both the real MainActivity, and its derivative MockActivity, test-side.

It also happens in a new Android project, with android version 4.3, and a very recent Eclipse. Plus Mockito 1.9.5. Any questions, maintainers?

The test case is trivial, and uses `ActivityUnitTestCase<MainActivity>`.

Has anyone seen this kinda stack trace before?

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Failed to mock class com.example.example.test.MockActivity

at com.example.example.test.SmartPhinsTest.test_mockito_mocks_activities(ExampleTest.java:39)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
```

And could someone found a testing-framework tag already?

The (trivial) code snip is:

```
package com.example.example.test;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Instrumentation;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase;

import com.example.example.MainActivity;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class ActivityTests extends ActivityUnitTestCase<MainActivity> {
    public ActivityTests(Class<MainActivity> activityClass) {
        super(activityClass);
    }
    public ActivityTests() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }
    Activity activity;
    Context targetContext;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        targetContext = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
        intent = new Intent(targetContext, MainActivity.class);
        super.setUp();
        startActivity(intent, null, null);
        activity = getActivity();
    }                
    public void test_mockito_mocks_activities() {            
        Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();
        File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        String path = cacheDir.getPath();
        System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", path); // "/storage/sdpath");
        MainActivity mockActivity = mock(MainActivity.class);
    }
}
```

I also added `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to both `AndroidManifest.xml` files. And, although most of the examples use `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`, it refuses to work for me - even in a greenfield project on another platform.

That fairly consistently gives me:

```
E/dalvikvm(3576): Could not find class 'android.app.LoaderManagerImpl', referenced from method MainActivity_Proxy.getLoaderManager
E/dalvikvm(3576): Could not find class 'android.app.Activity$NonConfigurationInstances', referenced from method MainActivity_Proxy.retainNonConfigurationInstances
```

Comment: Can  you show us the test case?  By the way, tagging this Mockito would have helped the people who can solve your problem see it earlier.

Comment: It turns out if I fix the /SdPath, then the app waits a solid minute, emits `E/dalvikvm(2132): Could not find class 'android.app.LoaderManagerImpl', referenced from method MockActivity_Proxy.getLoaderManager` to LogCat, and then PASSES. I'm adding the example code now but it's dirt-simple.

Comment: Why are you mocking the class under test?  Most of the time when I see mocks used, you mock the dependencies of the class under test, but the class itself of course can't be a mock because otherwise how will you test its functionality?

Comment: Because A> I'm not TDDing Android's Activity class; I need to TDD all the dumb routines I add onto it, and B> Android's Activity class is broken, with respect to TDD, because it couples with a Droid phone. I wanted to break the dependency on the stuff I don't need to test.

Answer (score 6):

In the setup method put this:

```
// To solve some issue with Dexmaker
System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", getContext().getCacheDir().getPath());
```

Comment: That's one of several permutations I tried of fixing the cache.